# In-text citation for research paper. How to look for a "source" when a reference is an article on a website?

Tags: citation-style

I am an I.T. student and currently working on my capstone project it is equivalent to research paper or thesis for some college courses. I usually do an in-text citation using APA style. For example:

> According to Jones (1998), "Students often had difficulty using APA
>   style, especially when it was their first time" (p. 199).

As you can see at the last part (p. 199) that is the "source". At least, that is what I understand from my professor's explanation.

Since almost of my reference are taken from websites particularly an article which have no pages on it. My question is, how should I put a source in my research paper if a website have no pages?

I already do my research about this problem, but it is still very vague to me.

Comment: This is my first time. How should I do it?

Comment: I think it will be better for you to just ask the question on the other site and then delete this question, or ask someone else to if you're not able.

Comment: What does the style guide of your university tell you about citing websites?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of our site is that you demonstrate your initial research. For me, [official APA guidance](http://www.apastyle.org/learn/quick-guide-on-references.aspx) is near the top of web search results, and will give you the answer. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a full understanding of how we can help you.

Comment: I don't really see anything to answer here.  As someone from EL&U commented, the answer is on the APA website.

Answer (score 1):

when you are citing a particular document or piece of information from a website, include both a reference list entry and an in-text citation.

The key to creating the reference list entry is to determine the type of content on the web page. Basically, provide the following four pieces of information:
Author, A. (date). Title of document [Format description]. Retrieved from http://xxxxxxxxx

The in-text citation includes the author and date (Author, date), as with any other APA Style citation.

You can read more about this from the APA style guide website at: http://www.apastyle.org/learn/quick-guide-on-references.aspx

Check out the **"More Information"** section for further clarification on what to do if there is no author, year or page numbers.

I hope this is what you were asking.  Andy ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The "source" is actually not just the page number, but also the author(s) name(s) and the publication date. In APA style, the page number is only included when you're directly quoting the source, so if you're just summarizing the information you found on a website, this won't be a problem at all.

However, if you are directly quoting something, then you will want to make sure you have author(s), date, and a reference of some kind to the quote's location in the document, even if you can't use page numbers.  Here's a page on APA's website about including all of those elements, even when it isn't intuitive: http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/11/how-to-cite-something-you-found-on-a-website-in-apa-style.html?_ga=1.195825445.860168388.1455210412